# Does the improper integral converges?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Proof the convergenсe of the integral: $ \int\limits_{1}^{\infty} \sin (x \ln x) d x.$ Tried to change variables, no result. May you suggest something? And may you also suggest some books with a focus on examples? Feeling trouble with this type of integrals.

Comment: Are you sure this integral converges? It looks suspiciously divergent...

Comment: Sure. It is stated that integral converges conditionally.

Comment: I doubt it since $\;x\log x\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty\implies \sin x\log x\;$  wobbles between $\;-1\;$ and $\;1\;$ ... But perhaps it converges. And who is "it" that stated the integral converges conditionally?

Comment: I mean that it is written in answers for this task.

Comment: Have you considered integration by parts?

Comment: Integrating by parts does not give anything new.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $f(x) = x\ln x.$ Then $f'(x) \ge 1,$ so $f$ is a nice 1-1 map from $[1,\infty)$ t0 $[0,\infty).$ Make the change of variables $x= f^{-1}(y).$ You get

$$\int_0^\infty (\sin y)(f^{-1})'(y)\,dy.$$

You are set up for Dirichlet's test.

Comment: But for Dirichlet's test you need $ (f^{-1})'(y) $ to be monotonous and $(f^{-1})'(y) \to 0$. Why is that true?

Comment: There's a well known formula for the derivative of the inverse. Time to dust it off.

Comment: Get it! Thanks!

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?

Comment: I voted for your answer.